# Generalization of alternative coin flipping problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, markov-chains

> Two players $A$ and $B$ are flipping a fair coin alternatively, with $A$ starting first. 
>   The first player to obtain head wins the game. Then the probability that $A$ wins this game is $\frac{2}{3}.$

The answer above can be obtained easily by using recursion: Let $p$ be the probability that $A$ wins. Then 
$$p = \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{2}(1-p).$$ 
Solving the equation above leads to $p = \frac{2}{3}.$

Another extended question:

> The same setting as above. The game ends if there is a head followed by a tail and the player who obtains tail wins the game. Then the probability that $A$ wins the game is $\frac{4}{9}.$

The answer above can be obtained in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1455393/first-to-the-sequence-ht-between-two-players).

I notice that the answer to the second question is just a square of the first question. 
I wonder whether there is a generalization. 
More precisely,

> Fixed a natural number $n.$ Two players $A$ and $B$ flip a fair coin alternatively, with $A$ starting first. The game ends if there exists a subsequence $HTHT...HT$ with length $n$ and the player who obtains the last toss in the subsequence wins the game. What is the probability that $A$ wins?

Note that if $n$ is odd, then the last toss is $H$ and $n$ is even, the last toss is $T$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_n$ be the probability we are looking for.

If $n$ is odd, player $A$ wins if he looses in $n-1$ game and the next toss is Heads; if the next toss is Tails the game restarts with $A$ being the second player; so

$$p_n=P_{Heads}(1-p_{n-1})+P_{Tails}(1-p_n)=\frac12(1-p_{n-1})+\frac12(1-p_n)$$

and
$$p_n=\frac{2-p_{n-1}}{3}$$

or ([thanks @J.W.Tanner](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3494603/42926))
$$p_n=\dfrac12-\dfrac12\left(-\dfrac13\right)^n$$

The solution for "$n$ is even" case is the same up to Heads $\leftrightarrow$ Tails swap; since $P_{Heads}=P_{Tails}=1/2$ it does not matter.

Comment: I don't think the main equation covers all the cases.  What if $A$ wins the $n-1$ game?  Also, I would intuitively guess (not sure) that $p_\infty = 1/2$, but that doesn't satisfy the recurrence.

Comment: @antkam see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3494598/42926 for convergence.

Comment: you're right about the convergence.  i made a silly arithmetic mistake.  :)  but i still don't understand the first equation.  sorry for being slow...  also, wouldnt the logic be slightly different if $n$ is even?

Comment: @antkam I updated the solution to make it more clear. When in doubt, drawing correspondent Markov chain helps.

Comment: But when $n$ is even, the winning string ends in T.  So if the next toss is H, then it is not equivalent to the game re-starting with A being 2nd player.